# Disable or hide row/column in detailsview when inserting?

Tags: vb.net, gridview, datasource, detailsview, sqldatasource

When in insert mode detailsview, there are some parameters that I would like to disable or hide. The columns are autogenerated.

Doesn't work:

```
DetailsView3.Rows(5).Visible = False
```

or

```
DetailsView3.Rows(5).Enabled = False
```

I'm lost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

X.X

Do it after you databind.

Answer (score 0):

**In C#:**

```
protected void DetailsView2_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 if (DetailsView2.CurrentMode == DetailsViewMode.Insert)
 {
  DetailsView2.Rows[5].Visible = false;
 }
}
```